# How to select last salary change date from the list?

Tags: sql

Hi I have a table as follows

```
EmplID     Name     Effdt            Salary   Action

1000       XXXX     01-01-2010       5000      HIR     ----hire
1000       XXXX     01-05-2011       6000      PRO     ----promotion
1000       XXXX     01-03-2012       6000      TER     -----TErminate
1001       YYYY     01-01-2010       8000      HIR     ----hire
1001       YYYY     01-05-2011       6000      PRO     ----promotion
1001       YYYY     01-03-2012       4000      Trn     -----TRANSFER
1001       yyyy     01-04-2012       4000      TER     -----TERMINATE
```

From the above table I want to select salary change date as:

```
EMPLID  EFFDT
1000    01-05-2011
1001    01-03-2012
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Wait, in your example output data, the date for empl 1001 is *not* the most recent change. Is that a mistake?

Comment: The most recent for 1001 would have been 01-05-2011 , not 01-03-2011.

Comment: He wants the change date I think, not the most recent, i.e. 01-05-2011 as salary change 5000->6000 and 01-03-2012 as it went from 6000->4000 which begs the question whats the output for multiple changes? the most recent? are there specific Actions that generate a change?

Comment: @Michael - Careful, you've possibly mis-understood.  If there is a record, but the salary is the same as for the preceding record, the salary has *not* changed...

Comment: @AlexK. for the user 1001 the change date = last date 4000 (01-04-2012) -> 6000 (01-05-2011)

Comment: @user1194923 - What variety of SQL?  MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle?  Some have different syntax that can help here...

Comment: @AlexK. - The OP needs the most recent change, it's in the title...  `How to select last salary change date from the list?`

Comment: @Dems, yes, last change, for OP, is the most recent date before max date. See: 1000    01-05-2011 (max date = 01-03-2012), 1001    01-03-2012 (max date = 01-04-2012)

Comment: Congratulations! You've asked a deceptively complex question and gotten us all to give you simple answers that don't quite work. I suspect the best answer to your real question may depend on what DBMS you're using. Can you please specify?

Answer (score 3):

You may try this query (supposing that termination date does not change the salary and all the others do, including hire):

```
SELECT EMPLID, MAX(Effdt)
FROM Tble
WHERE Action != 'TER'
GROUP BY EMPLID
```

It groups by Employer ID and within a group selects the last date.

Comment: take a look, OP search for second max date. See @AlexK comment.

Comment: Last date for user 1000 is 01-03-2012. I  think that this is not a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple `MAX()` aggregate on the `Effdt`. I would recommend reading up on SQL aggregate functions and `GROUP BY` clauses, as this is an elementary task.

```
SELECT 
  EmplID,
  MAX(Effdt) AS LastChange
FROM employees
GROUP BY EmplID
```

Comment: take a look, OP search for second max date. See @AlexK comment.

Comment: Mistakes like this (answering a question different from that intended by the OP) are reasons to avoid potentially patronising remarks ;)  *[Not that I've ever learned that lesson though]*

Answer (score 0):

You should get max second date: max date excluding real max date:

```
Select taf.emplid, max( taf.Effdt )
from
   tableAsFollows taf
inner join
  (Select emplid, max( Effdt )
  from
   tableAsFollows taf2
  group by emplid ) t_max
on taf.emlpid = t_max.emplid
where taf.Effdt < t_max.Effdt
group by taf.emplid
```

If your dbms supports CTE then use it insteat this approach.

Comment: it looks like somewhere in the question there is a mistake, because for user 1000 he outputs the last date

Comment: I would not assume that the last *change* is always the second from last record, what about employees that have not terminated?  It may be possible to assume that you should ignore the `TER` action records if they exist...

Comment: @Demls, I don't know. Question is ambiguous. Does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming hiring and termination don't count as salary changes, you need a slight variation on Tim and Michael's answers.

```
SELECT 
  EmplID,
  MAX(Effdt) AS LastChange
FROM employees
WHERE Action NOT IN ('HIR','TER')
GROUP BY EmplID
```

There may be other actions that don't qualify as a "salary change." If so, add them to the `WHERE` clause. Alternatively, you could use an inclusive list in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the last change isn't always the second from last record, and that it could be any where in the chain.

```
SELECT
  current.EmplID,
  COALESCE(MAX(next.Effdt), current.Effdt)
FROM
  yourTable   AS current
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable   AS next
    ON  next.EmplID = current.EmplID
    AND next.Effdt  = (SELECT MIN(Effdt)
                       FROM   yourTable AS lookup
                       WHERE  EmplID = current.EmplID
                         AND  Effdt  > current.Effdt)
    AND current.Salary <> next.Salary
GROUP BY
  current.EmplID
```

*(The LEFT JOIN and COALESCE() cope with a chain of just one item)*

If the only time there can be a new record with the same salary is on termination, you could just ignore termination records...

```
SELECT   EMPLID, MAX(Effdt)
FROM     yourTable
WHERE    Action != 'TER'
GROUP BY EMPLID
```

To get *the best* solution, we need to know more.  You need to describe exactly how the data can behave :)

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms supports CTE and if the salary that is terminate can be exclude. Then something like this might do the trick:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY EmplID ORDER BY Effdt DESC) AS iRank,
    tbl.EmplID,
    tbl.Effdt
FROM
    yourTable AS tbl
WHERE
    tbl.[Action]!='TER'
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.iRank=1
```